# Did something stupid and made a bad reg edit, only have the executed script

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, windows-10, regedit

In the attempt to have a shortcut to one of my folders in windows explorer (just like the one drive shortcut for example) I executed a reg edit that placed a literal " place holder " of a non-functioning folder in the explorer.

Unsure how to remove this I went on my way to stack-overflow in the hope someone here could point me how to reverse my changes.

To show you what I did I have attached the powershell script and .reg below.

powershell:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
  Add custom shortcut to Windows Explorer's sidebar

.DESCRIPTION
  Adds a custom shortcut to Windows Explorer's sidebar

.NOTES
  AUTHOR : Oliver Lipkau
  VERSION: 1.0.0 - OL - Initial Code
#>

$hGUID = (New-GUID).guid
do
{
  $displayName = Read-Host "Other Drives"
} while (!$displayName)

do
{
  $targetPath = Read-Host "C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive .other"
} while (!$targetPath)

$defaultIcon = "imageres.dll,137"
Write-Verbose "Little help to icons: https://diymediahome.org/windows-icons-reference-list-with-details-locations-images/"
$icon = Read-Host "Shortcut Icon [default: $defaultIcon]"
if (!$icon) {$icon = $defaultIcon}

"Creating $displayName"
Write-Verbose "GUID: $hGUID"

$paths = @('HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID',
  'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID',
  'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID',
  'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID',
  'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID',
  'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID',
  'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID'
)

$Reg = @"
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

"@

foreach ($path in $paths)
{
  $reg += @"
[$path\{$hGUID}]
@="$displayName"
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000032
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001

[$path\{$hGUID}\DefaultIcon]
@="$icon"

[$path\{$hGUID}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[$path\{$hGUID}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[$path\{$hGUID}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="$targetPath"

[$path\{$hGUID}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028

"@
}

$reg += @"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{$hGUID}]
@="$displayName"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{$hGUID}"=dword:00000001
"@

$reg | Out-file registry.reg
regedit /s registry.reg
```

Reg edit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}]
@="Other Drives"
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000032
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,137"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive .other"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}]
@="Other Drives"
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000032
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,137"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive .other"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}]
@="Other Drives"
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000032
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,137"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive .other"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}]
@="Other Drives"
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000032
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,137"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive .other"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}]
@="Other Drives"
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000032
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,137"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive .other"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}]
@="Other Drives"
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000032
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,137"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive .other"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}]
@="Other Drives"
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000032
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,137"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive .other"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}]
@="Other Drives"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e}"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for... you have all the key paths you need to delete in the `.reg` file, what do you need help with?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delayed reply, I am pretty new to all this and I have tried deleting f8a7e615-74ea-4c19-bdfe-be0c17fd654e from the reg editor but it kept the placeholder, all that happened was a change in icon. Figured I'd ask for advice before deleting something perm. and screwing up again.